# fetch resolves even if 404?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

Using this code :

```
fetch('notExists') // <---- notice 
    .then(
        function(response)
        {
           alert(response.status)
        }
    )
    .catch(function(err)
    {
       alert('Fetch Error : ', err);
    });
```

This promise *resolves*.

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

> It returns a promise that resolves to the Response to that request,
>    whether it is successful or not.

Isn't it strange that a failed ajax request is resolved even if it goes to an non-existing resource ?

I mean  - what next ? a  `fetch` to a server which is down and still get a resolved promise ?

I know I can investigate at the `ok` property at the `response` object , but still -

**Question**

Why do a fetch gets resolved for   a completely bad request ( non existing resource  ).

[BTW , jquery request  , does  get rejected](http://jsbin.com/pukurolego/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: It has to resolve so you can process the error code.

Comment: @Barmar So why not on the catch/reject  handler?

Comment: Are you expecting the authors of the fetch standard to reply? Because they would be the ones who could answer this without speculation.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm just asking to find an answer. I'm not expecting Henrik  to answer here :-)

Comment: For the one who suggested to close by opinion , the last thing i'm after is an opinion , I'm after an answer becuase as an API builder , I want to get better. I'm after the **professional** reason.

Comment: Your question probably got a close vote because you asked "What is the reason behind..." which is not really knowable by any of us.  You'd have to have been in the actual design discussions to know why exactly that was chosen so if that's really what you wanted to know, then you'd have to go ask on some mailing list associated with that interface so you could speak to someone who actually knows the "reason".  We can only explain why it is a reasonable choice or how to use it as is, not exactly "why" it was chosen that way.

Comment: per your edit... "because that's how they decided to do it"

Comment: Kevin you're a genius, stay around

Comment: I agree, 404 not to go down the error path is bonkers.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

A `fetch()` call is only rejected if the network request itself fails for some reason (host not found, no connection, server not responding, etc...).

Any result back from the server (404, 500, etc...) is considered a successful request from the promise point of view.  Conceptually, you made a request from the server and the server answered you so from the networking point of view, the request finished successfully.

You need to then test that successful response to see if has the type of answer you wanted.  If you want a 404 to be a rejection, you could code that yourself:

```
fetch('notExists').then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        // make the promise be rejected if we didn't get a 2xx response
        throw new Error("Not 2xx response", {cause: response});
    } else {
         // got the desired response
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    // some error here
});
```

You could even make your own `myFetch()` that just does this automatically for you (converts any non-200 response status to a rejection).

> What is the reason behind a resolved promise for a a completely bad
> request ( non existing resource / server down).

First off, server down will not generate a successful response - that will reject.

A successful response is generated if you successfully connect to the server, send it a request and it returns a response (any response).  As for "why" the designers of the `fetch()` interface decided to base the rejection on this, it's a bit hard to say without talking to someone who was actually involved in the design of that interface, but it seems logical to me.  This way the rejection tells you whether the request got through and got a valid response.  It's up to your code to decide what to do with the response.  You can, of course, create your own wrapper function that modifies that default behavior.

Comment: Oh well , I know that there is no place to compare but `$.ajax` to `//a` does rejected. http://jsbin.com/pukurolego/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I don't think you're jsbin example is doing what you think it is.  If I `console.log()` the reject error, I see this `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE  http://0.0.0.22/`.  I don't know exactly how jQuery behaves, but your jsbin isn't testing the right thing.

Comment: You're right , my bad , didn't see it. I need a rest .

Comment: I guess you could say that it's about protocol layers. If you get 404, your _HTTP_ request was successful, and the response was 404. The promise rejects if there is no HTTP status code at all, because whatever makes a HTTP connection successful didn't work. This is in line with other tools like `curl`, who return exit code 0 for any HTTP code, and only fail if no HTTP code is applicable.

Answer (score 7):

Use this code...

```
fetch(`https://fercarvo.github.io/apps/integradora/DB/corpus.json`)
.then(async (data) => {
    if (data.ok) {
        data = await data.json()
        //Here you have your data...
    }
}).catch(e => console.log('Connection error', e))
```

Answer (score 3):

Reject handler is for networking and CORS errors iirc. If the request reaches the server and it responds with a valid http response, the promise gets fulfilled, even if the response is of code 4xx or 5xx.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @fernando-caravajal example (which resulted easier for me for the async/await use) I made this slightly modified version below, for a post query, with parameters sent. I added the `throw new Error` statement as I had trouble to catch the failure on `response.ok == false`.

```
/**
 *  Generic fetch function
 */
function fetchData(url,parameters,callback) {

  fetch(url,{
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(parameters),
  })
  .then(async(response) => {
      // status 404 or 500 will set ok to false
      if (response.ok) {
          // Success: convert data received & run callback
          result = await response.json();
          callback(result);
      }
      else {
          throw new Error(response.status + " Failed Fetch ");
      }
  }).catch(e => console.error('EXCEPTION: ', e))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your tip, used your code and managed to solve the problem. I think I was forgetting to put in response the Async function

Answer (score 1):

For people that like to use `await` and `try catch`'s suppose two server scenarios:

1. **Successful 200 call** would return

```json
{
  "user": "1234",
  "token": "1231411acad..."
}
```

2. **Failed 404 call** would return

```json
{
  "error": "There was an error"
}
```

In your client-side JS you can handle it like:

```js
try {
  const {user, token, error} = await fetch('API_URL', {
    method: "POST",
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ ... }),
  }).then((response) => response.json());

  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  // Continue successful logic here...
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  // Continue failed logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, fetch only returns an error in case of a proper networking issue. A "down" server will not return 4XX, it will return nothing or 5XX depending on how it's "down".
I tend to use axios over fetch mainly because this issue makes me write a lot more code.