# async await fetch undefined. How to handle?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am currently learning `async await fetch` and I've created the following example to help me learn.

The working example below:

1. fetches three random json records from a Public API
2. extracts the `url` from each return `json`
3. creates three `img` elements
4. appends three `img` elements to the document body.

Notice that `promise2` has an intentionally wrong path set to force a http status 404.

How do I handle this error if it was to happen to any of the three promises?

```js
// the big promise.
  async function getAsyncData() {

    try {

      // attempt to resolve 3 individual unrelated promises...
      let promise1  = await fetch('https://dummyimage.com/48x48/4caf50/ffffff.jpg&text=.jpg');
      let promise2  = await fetch('https://dummyimage.com/bad/url/here/48x48/e91e63/ffffff.png&text=.png');
      let promise3  = await fetch('https://dummyimage.com/48x48/00bcd4/ffffff.gif&text=.gif');

      // we create an html img element and set its src attribute to the thumbnailUrl...
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = promise1.url;
      // ...and add it to our html document body...
      document.body.append(img);

      // we create an html img element and set its src attribute to the thumbnailUrl...
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = promise2.url;
      // ...and add it to our html document body...
      document.body.append(img);

      // we create an html img element and set its src attribute to the thumbnailUrl...
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = promise3.url;
      // ...and add it to our html document body...
      document.body.append(img);

    } catch (error) {

      console.log('Try/Catch block error:', error);

    }

    // return {


    // }

  }

  getAsyncData();
```

Comment: Try [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).  It doesn't reject everything in the case where just one promise rejects (which is what `Promise.all` would do).  Another note is that your `fetch`es can't be parallel if you use `await` the way you are in your example.

Comment: I see. Ok. So as for `fetch` being unable to be parallel... Argh! Youtube examples... Are you proposing I `await` the `fetch` and then `await` a `json` of the `fetch`?

Comment: Updated code to reflect what I think you meant.

Comment: @suchislife, build the Promises into an array,  and use a for await of loop to iterate on the Promises.  That way you get the best of both worlds (depending on what you are trying to do)

Comment: As opposed to `Promise.All` which is a all or nothing kinda thing? I think I'm getting this. So `Promise.All` for related promises and `Promise.allSettled()` for say... a thumbnail gallery of random images that require no knowledge of one another to exist or fail.

Comment: I'm on FF 68 which doesn't support `allSettled`.  I would put all the `fetch`es into an array and use them there.  It's OK to mix Promises and async/await.  It's all about ease of use and trying to avoid callback hell.  It lets us write synchronous ***looking*** code.

Comment: I have finally found a public Image API that is hosted on a decent server (NGINX) and added a few things to it. It implements your solution as originally intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Promise.allSettled you can run all the fetch calls in parallel and wait for them all to complete.

```js
const test = async() => {
  const promise1  = await fetch('https://dummyimage.com/48x48/4caf50/ffffff.jpg&text=.jpg')
    .then(r => r.url)

  const promise2  = await fetch('https://dummyimage.com/bad/url/here/48x48/e91e63/ffffff.png&text=.png')
    .then(r => r.url)

  const promise3  = await fetch('https://dummyimage.com/48x48/00bcd4/ffffff.gif&text=.gif')
    .then(r => r.url)

  const results = await Promise.allSettled([promise1, promise2, promise3])

  console.log(results);

}

test();
```

For older support you would need to use a promise that would catch any errors from the fetch.

```js
function makeCall () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetch('https://dummyimage.com/48x48/4caf50/ffffff.jpg&text=.jpg')
    .then(r => console.log(r.url))
    .catch(error => resolve({ error }))
  })
}

const test = async() => {
  const promise1 = makeCall()
  const promise2 = makeCall()
  const promise3 = makeCall()

  const results = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])

  console.log(results)

}

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

.error and try/catch is not what you are looking for:
[fetch resolves even if 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297345/fetch-resolves-even-if-404)
You need to check the value of `response.ok`.  fetch only throws errors on network problems, not error responses.

```js
// Background Colors
const bgHexColors   = ['f44336', 'e91e63', '9c27b0', '673ab7', '3f51b5', '2196f3', '03a9f4', '00bcd4', '009688', '4caf50', '8bc34a', 'cddc39', 'ffeb3b', 'ffc107', 'ff9800', 'ff5722', '795548', '9e9e9e', '607d8b'];
// Foreground Colors
const fgHexColors   = ['ffffff'];
// Image File Extensions
const imgExtensions = ['.png', '.gif', '.jpg'];

// First, we initialize an empty array for promises.
let myPromises = [];

// We then populate this array with 24 promises.
for(let i = 0; i < 24; i++){

  let imgWidth     = 48;
  let imgHeight    = 48;
  let bgHexColor   = bgHexColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgHexColors.length)];
  let fgHexColor   = fgHexColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fgHexColors.length)];
  let imgExtension = imgExtensions[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgExtensions.length)];
  let imgText      = imgExtension;

  // We declare the promise to be added and...
  let myPromise = getRandomImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, bgHexColor, fgHexColor, imgExtension, imgText);

  // add each promise to the myPromises array.
  myPromises.push(myPromise);

}

// We create an html span element and...
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.style.color = '#ffffff';
// We set the element's span text to Please wait...
span.innerText = 'Please wait...';
// We add the span element to the document body.
document.body.append(span);


// Promise.all requires an array.
Promise.all(myPromises).then((myResponses) => {

  // debug
  // console.log(myResponses);

  // We create an html img element and...
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.color = '#ffffff';
  // We set the element's span text to Please wait...
  span.innerText = 'Done.';
  // We add the span element to the document body.
  document.body.append(span);

  // We create an html img element and...
  let br = document.createElement('br');
  // We add the br element to the document body.
  document.body.append(br);

  // for each promise resolved...
  for(let i = 0; i < myResponses.length; i++) {

    // We check its returned object containing the resolverImg...
    if(myResponses[i].resolverImg !== null) {

      // We create an html img element and...
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      // We set the element's image source to the resolverImg url returned and..
      img.src = myResponses[i].resolverImg;
      // We add the img element to the document body.
      document.body.append(img);

    }

  }

}).catch(err => console.error(err));

// The individual Promise.
// Accepts 5 arguments; image size, background color, foreground color, image file extension, image text.
async function getRandomImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, bgHexColor, fgHexColor, imgExt, imgText) {

  // The Response interface of the Fetch API represents the response to a request.
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

  // We initialize the image and status as null...
  let myResolverImg      = null;
  let myResolverStatus   = null;

  // We use a Try/Catch block to check if the resolverImg exists...
  try {

    // We create a fetch async resolver...
    let myResolver       = await fetch(`https://dummyimage.com/${imgWidth}x${imgHeight}/${bgHexColor}/${fgHexColor}${imgExt}&text=${imgText}`);

    // debug
    // console.log(myResolver);

    if(myResolver.ok) {
      // if it exists, change it from null to a valid image url path.
      myResolverImg      = myResolver.url;
      myResolverStatus   = myResolver.status;
    }

    } catch (err) {
    // if fetch network error...
    console.error('Fetch network error.');
  }

  // Return js object containing image url OR, resolverImg REMAINS null as initially declared.
  return {
       resolverImg: myResolverImg,
    resolverStatus: myResolverStatus
  };

}
```