# Fetch returning 404 error: "GET <urlthatIwasfetchinghere> 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I am using fetch and it is to my understanding that 404 codes should happen but not GET 404 errors when fetching from a non existent page. I am using the open weather map api. The error that I'm getting is `GET ${forcastUrl} 404 (Not Found)`.

My fetch statement looks like this:

```
function fetchingForcast(forcastUrl){
    fetch(forcastUrl)
    .then(validateWeatherResponse)
    .then(responseToJSON)
    .then(dat => {
      forcastDat = dat;
      updateforcastPanel();
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

```
function validateWeatherResponse(response){
  if (response.ok){
    return response;
  } else {
    throw Error("response.ok: "+ response.ok);
  }
```

`validateWeatherResponse` checks if the response is ok and if not, it throws an error. However, when it does throw an error, it should go to catch and console.log the error. When I use the debug devtool on chrome, the error appears to happen as soon as `validateWeatherResponse` is called.

Besides for this error, my code works when I input a correct website. It is to my understanding that 404 errors should not occur so I'd like to understand why this is happening.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't work with promises much, but I believe your `validateWeatherResponse` needs to return a promise to allow chaining. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining

Comment: @Will Thanks for commenting! I don't believe that is the issue because according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining, looking at the first example, the 2nd chain/then takes in a parameter of a function that doesn't returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN's HTTP status code documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status):

> **404 Not Found**
> The server can not find the requested resource. In the browser, this means the URL is not recognized. In an API, this can also mean that the endpoint is valid but the resource itself does not exist. This response code is probably the most famous one due to its frequent occurrence on the web.

The 404 error code means that the website or endpoint that you requested **does not exist**, which is definitely expected if you request a non-existent page.

If you are still confused about the error, please tell me in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for answering! According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297345/fetch-resolves-even-if-404 , however, I should not be getting this error and it should be catched instead. I was also under the impression that having errors is bad practice so I want to avoid them.

Comment: @TheShagod ah. That thread you linked actually says that 404 errors will not be passed to the catch: `A fetch() call is only rejected if the network request itself fails for some reason (host not found, no connection, server not responding, etc...).` So, any response from the server (including 404 error) is considered a success by fetch. You can validate the status code in the `.then` and proceed accordingly. Obviously having errors is not a good thing, so you should fix the error by not requesting non-existent pages!

Comment: The project, I'm working on has a user search for a city and my app returns the weather forecast. If the user tries to mess with the app and search for a non-existent page, I am unsure how to avoid this. My fetch statement does catch the error to "console.log(error)" but fetch in addition sends an error. My `validateWeatherResponse` throws an error which then the fetch can catch if there is a 404 error (`response.ok` would be false).

Comment: @TheShagod if the user is intentionally searching for a non-existent page, there's nothing you can do except tell them `No Results` or `Location Not Found`. Maybe show an `alert()` if the status code is 404?