# not able to catch error in axios react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making API call using axios in reactjs project but somehow I am not able to catch the error. I am getting **404** but not able to catch it. can somebody tell me what's wrong?

abc.js

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `my_base_url`,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

xyz.js

```
export const createProcessApiCall = (param) => {
  return API.post("/v1/process1", param);
};
```

zzz.js

```
  const postData = async (param) => {
    await createProcessApiCall(param)
      .then((response) => {
          setApiData(response.data.data);
          setIsSuccess(response.data.isSuccess);    
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setIsError(true);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Because it's not really an error. `axios` only raise error if the error is, let say, network error or such. 404 error, on the other hand, mean that the request was delivered. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297345/fetch-resolves-even-if-404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are combinining async code with sync code, try to use either asynchron :

```
   const postData = async (param) => {
    try {
       const result = await createProcessApiCall(param)
    }
    catch(err) {
         setIsError(true);
 
    }   
    };
```

Or synchron :

```
const postData = (param) => {
    createProcessApiCall(param)
      .then((response) => {
          setApiData(response.data.data);
          setIsSuccess(response.data.isSuccess);    
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setIsError(true);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Any status code different the sequence included between 200-299, you need to get at catch:

```
  const postData = async (param) => {
    await createProcessApiCall(param)
      .then((response) => {
          setApiData(response.data.data);
          setIsSuccess(response.data.isSuccess);    
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // @TODO parse err
        console.log(e.response);
        setIsError(true);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(res=>{return res}, (error) => {
 if (error.response.status !== 401) {
   throw error;
}

if (typeof error.response.data.error.name !== "undefined") {
   //do something on the error
}
});
```

its better to use axios interceptor to catch the error