# fetch function keeps throwing GET http://localhost:9000/Image.png 404 (Not Found) error in the browser even when i catch it

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api

I have a folder of a bunch of images. And i want to delete unnecessary ones to save some memory and fetch time. I cant check if i need the image or not before the fetch. I can only know if i need it if the image is there or not.
If the image is not there i want to just return null otherwise i wanna return HTMLImageElement with the image src.

I have a function thats responsible for cashing images.

```
async getCashedImage() {
    try {
        const blob = await this.getRequestedImage(imgURL,{method: "GET"}) 
        const imgObjectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                    let img = new Image()
                    img.src = imgObjectUrl
                    this.imageMap.set(key, img)
                    this.fetchQueue = this.fetchQueue.filter((val) => {
                        return val != key
                    })
                    return img
    } catch (error) {
        return null
    }
}
```

And i have a function for getting those images.

```
private async getRequestedImage(url: string, config: RequestInit) : Promise<Blob> {
    const response = await fetch(url,config)
    if(!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
    }
    return await response.blob()
}
```

And whatever i try to do i keep getting the `GET http://localhost:9000/Image.png 404 (Not Found)` error in console.

I just want the function to return null and not throw an error in case there is no image found.

***Edit***:
Let me rephraze my question.
Im getting the 404 response, throwing an error and catching it actually but the error still gets thrown in the console like i didnt catch it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch resolves even if 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297345/fetch-resolves-even-if-404)

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you select. [tag:fetch] is marked as DO NOT USE, and the behaviour of `fetch` is not specific to TypeScript.

Comment: ooh woops i didnt realise sorry :)

Comment: @Quentin so i know 404 is a valid response and not an error. and after i catch it, it still gets thrown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Took me hours to find this. But apparently if the image doesnt exist and you try to fetch it even if you handle to 404 the browser will still display an error on its own. So its more of a browser thing then the actuall code....